# Fetching objects and combining them in one list

Tags: python, django

I'm fetching two kinds of objects from my database like so:

```
def browse_freelancers(request):
    users = User.objects.filter(type=1)

    freelancers = []

    for user in users:
        freelancers.append(Freelancer.object.get(user=user))
```

This gives me a QuerySet of users and a list of Freelancers. Coming from Java or C# lists and their ease of use have always confused me (for some reason). Is there a way to elegantly combine the QuerySet and list into one list where a User object is coupled with their related Freelancer object?

```
#models.py

class Freelancer(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    biography = models.TextField(default="")
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True)

    object = UserManager()

class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Freelancer'),
    (2, 'Client'),
)

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    verify_key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=16, null=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: I am sure there is a way to make this without iterating over `users`, but we have to see relationships in models to write it. Could you add you `models.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to build up the separate list in the first place, nor do you have to query Freelancers specifically. For any User instance, `user.freelancer` will give you the related Freelancer object via the one-to-one relationship.

The only problem with that is that the first time you do that access for any User you will incur another database call (subsequent access from the same User instance will be cached, though). You can avoid this by doing `select_related` on the initial query:

```
users = User.objects.filter(type=1).select_related('freelancer')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the freelancers using something like:

```
freelancers = Freelancer.objects.filter(user__type=1)
```

Since freelancer has a one-to-one with user, `freelancer.user` will give you the associated user.

As an optimization, if you know you are going to access all the users, you could do:

```
Freelancer.objects.filter(user__type=1).select_related('user')
```

This fetches both Freelancers and Users from the db.